# How to auto hide tooltipster

Tags: jquery, ionic-framework

I want showing little popup show text like tool-tip in ionic. So I'm using Tooltipster [tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) here is my code :

```
.directive('tooltip', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (attrs.title) {
                var $element = $(element);
                $element.attr("title", attrs.title)
                $element.tooltipster({
                    theme: 'tooltipster-default',
                    animation: attrs.animation,
                    trigger: "click",
                    position: "top",
                    positionTracker: true,
                    maxWidth: 500,
                    autoClose: true,
                    contentAsHTML: true
                });
            }
        }
    };
})
```

Now, I am not able to hide auto after some time. I am using following [example](http://codepen.io/jdnichollsc/pen/zvZQrw?editors=1010). Can any one help to close.
I am also try following methods :

```
$element.tooltipster('hide');
$element.tooltipster('destroy');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the timer(in ms) event tooltip should live before closing, For more info [here](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/)

```
.directive('tooltip', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (attrs.title) {
                var $element = $(element);
                $element.attr("title", attrs.title)
                $element.tooltipster({
                    theme: 'tooltipster-default',
                    animation: attrs.animation,
                    trigger: "click",
                    position: "top",
                    positionTracker: true,
                    maxWidth: 500,
                    timer:500,
                    autoClose: true,
                    contentAsHTML: true
                });
            }
        }
    };
})
```